# Google Analytics - how can I track a page name using the new asynchronous code?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, web-analytics

I was using the below code provided by Google for Google Analytics.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
            document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
         ry {
                var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXX-X");
                pageTracker._trackPageview("PAGENAME");
            } catch (err) { }
 </script>
```

But Google has released Asynchronous Javascript Code (below).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

**My QUESTION is**: in the old code I used to track a page with PAGENAME (pageTracker._trackPageview("PAGENAME");). How can I do it using the new asynchronous code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite that third code line in the async tracking code and change it to the following:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'PAGENAME']);
```

This is documented [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview)

Answer (score 3):

RTFM: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview

Your example would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'PAGENAME']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

It's merely a case of specifying a second parameter.

Comment: No worries. Always worth doing a Google for "[product] documentation" first. It's how I found it ;-)

Comment: I wish SO can allow to mark multiple replies as ANSWERED. Mr. halfdan's reply was 6 seconds faster than yours.

Comment: Ah, boo-urns! Mine has two up-votes if you're wanting me to compete :-P